# How can I get `multirow` argument to fit its prespecified column width?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn, column-width

The content of `multirow` overflows horizontally:

[image]

I know that I can fix this by specifying a certain length instead of `*` in `\multirow{5}{*}{Polynomial Fit According to Eq. }`, but I want the width denoted by `*` be specified automatically and be exactly equal to the corresponding column width, which is `>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}C` in this case. Look, for example, at the row that begins with 'Approximate Cubic According to Eq.' The content automatically adjusts. This is exactly what I want, but it does not seem to apply with `\multirow` command.

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

    % Floats
    \usepackage{caption}

        \captionsetup{justification = centering}


    % Math
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
    \usepackage[]{mathtools}


    % Tables
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
        \newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }

    \renewcommand \tabularxcolumn [1] { >{ \centering } m{#1} }


        \newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
        \newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }
        \arraystretchdefault

        \newcommand {\scalelinespace} [1] {\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}}

        \newlength{\tabcolsepdefaultl}
        \setlength{\tabcolsepdefaultl}{2.12mm}
        \newcommand{\tabcolsepdefault}{ \setlength{\tabcolsep}{\tabcolsepdefaultl} }
        \tabcolsepdefault

        \newlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}
        \setlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}{2.12mm}
        \newcommand{\arraycolsepdefault}{ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{\arraycolsepdefaultl} }
        \arraycolsepdefault


    \usepackage{booktabs}   
    \usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[h t p]

    % Table options

    % Caption
    \caption{\Large \textbf{A table with multi-rows and multi columns}}
    \label{table:fit_WT_par}

    % Center the table
    \centering



    % Table contents
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}C *{2}{|C} *{2}{|C} *{2}{|C} }



        \toprule


        & 
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{ \textbf{WT Model} }
        \\
        \hline

        \textbf{Fit Type} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \textbf{GEV MP R} } &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \textbf{G58-850} } &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{E-92} }
        \\
        \hline


        \multirow{5}{*}{Polynomial Fit According to Eq. } &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{

            \multirow{5}{4.5 cm}{\RaggedLeft $c_{7 }= -9.7, \; c_{6} = 531$ $c_{5} = -122, \; c_{4} = 152$ $c_{3} = -111, \; c_{2} = 473$ $c_{1} = -10927270, \; c_{0} = 105$}

        } &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|} {


            \multirow{5}{4.5 cm}{\justifying $c_{8} = -1.30, \; c_{7} = 85.3$ $c_{6} = -236, \; c_{5} = 360$ $c_{4} = -328979, \; c_{3} = 184$ $c_{2} = -6194947, \; c_{1} = 113$ $c_{0} = -874$}

        } &
        \multicolumn{2}{c} {


            \multirow{5}{4.5 cm}{\centering $c_{9} = -0.0535, \; c_{8} = 2.79$ $c_{7} = -53.1, \; c_{6} = 364$ $c_{5} = 150, \; c_{4} = -416$ $c_{3} = 290, \; c_{2} = -972$ $c_{1} = 1609, \; c_{0} = -104$}

        }
        \\

        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ }
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|} {}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c} {}
        \\


        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|} {}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c} {}
        \\


        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|} {}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c} {}
        \\


        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|} {}
        &
        \multicolumn{2}{c} {}
        \\
        \hline



        Approximate Cubic According to Eq. &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering  $C_{p, \, max} = 0.3926$} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering $C_{p, \, max} = 0.4453$} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\centering $C_{p, \, max} = 0.4729$}
        \\
        \hline


        Exponential (Eq. ) &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering $K_{p} = 2.687, \; \beta = 2.201$} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering $K_{p} = 12.88, \; \beta = 1.532$} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\centering $K_{p} = 11.12, \; \beta = 1.564$}
        \\



        \bottomrule






    \end{tabularx}




\end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: recent version of `multirow` has added option which overtake width of column: for example, that column is of type `p{22mm}`, than `\multirow{2}{=}{<cell content>}`.

Comment: Your calculation for the width of the first column is wrong. What are trying to achieve? And why don't you use three $X$`columns instead of six through a systematic use of `\multicolumn{2}`?

Comment: @Zarko That was exactly what I am looking for. The content no longer overflows and it adjusts to fit within the width `>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}C`. Would you like to post this as an answer? :)

Comment: @Bernard I am trying to get the table to stretch and fill `textwidth` which is done with `tabularx`, but I also want the first column width be scaled depending on the rest of the other columns rather than pre-specified constant width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in your table you not need `\multirow` cells.
- however, if you persit to have them in your table design, you can exploit new features of `multirow` package, which offer new option `=` by which multiroe cell overtake defined width ov column. for example, that column is of type `p{22mm}`, than `\multirow{2}{=}{<cell content>}` has width 22mm.
- it is not clear, why you define seven columns when the table has only four.
- `multicolum`s (except one) are superfluous.
- i wouldn't have vertical rules in table
- for equations in second, third and fourth column are more readable, if thex are set in `array` nested in `tabularx` cells

[image]

(red lines indicate text border).

```
 \documentclass[]{IEEEtran}
% Floats
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{justification = centering}
% Math
%\usepackage{amsmath} % loaded by `mathtools`
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering} X }
\usepackage{siunitx} % <--- added

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{\Large \textbf{A table with multi-rows and multi columns}}
\label{table:fit_WT_par}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.85\textwidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.16\hsize}C
                           *{3}{>{\hsize=0.28\hsize}C}
                            @{}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{WT Model }}                      \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\textbf{Fit Type}
    & \textbf{GEV MP R} & \textbf{G58-850}  & \textbf{E-92}         \\
    \midrule
Polynomial Fit According to Eq.
    &   $\begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
        c_{7 }= -9.7            & c_{6} = 531   \\
        c_{5} = -122            & c_{4} = 152   \\
        c_{3} = -111            & c_{2} = 473   \\
        c_{1} = -\num{10927270} & c_{0} = 105
        \end{array}$
        &   $\begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
            c_{8} = -1.30           & c_{7} = 85.3  \\
            c_{6} = -236            & c_{5} = 360   \\
            c_{4} = -\num{328979}   & c_{3} = 184   \\
            c_{2} = -\num{6194947}  & c_{1} = 113   \\
            c_{0} = -874            &
        \end{array}$
            &   $\begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
            c_{9} = -0.0535 & c_{8} = 2.79  \\
            c_{7} = -53.1   & c_{6} = 364   \\
            c_{5} = 150     & c_{4} = -416  \\
            c_{3} = 290     & c_{2} = -972  \\
            c_{1} = 1609    & c_{0} = -104
            \end{array}$                    \\
    \midrule
Approximate Cubic According to Eq.
    & $C_{p,\max} = 0.3926$
        & $C_{p,\max} = 0.4453$
            & $C_{p,\max} = 0.4729$         \\
    \midrule
Exponential (Eq. )
    & $K_{p} = 2.687,\beta = 2.201$
        & $K_{p} = 12.88,\beta = 1.532$
            & $K_{p} = 11.12,\beta = 1.564$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

- in case, that you like to have table width equal `\textwidth` than rešlace

`\begin{tabularx}{0.85\textwidth}{...}`

width

`\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{...}`

in above code i remove all not used packages and your definitions in preamble, which are not relevant for this table.

Comment: I remember using this table when I was very novice in using LaTeX. More importantly, I deliberately used `multirow` and `multicolumn` because I wanted to verify that I understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need any multirow,and only 4 columns. Here is a much simpler code, with the first column 1/3 of the other columns width. Also, you should use `booktabs` with vertical rules: horizontal and vertical rules don't intersect properly. I replaced `\bottomrule` with `\Xhline` from `makecell. Last point: needless to load`amsmath`if you load`mathtools` – the latter does it for you.
    \documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

```
    % Floats
    \usepackage{caption}
        \captionsetup{justification = centering}

    % Math
    \usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
    \usepackage[]{mathtools}

    % Tables
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
        \newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }

    \renewcommand \tabularxcolumn [1] { >{ \centering } m{#1} }

        \newcommand {\arraystretchdefaultl} {1.3}
        \newcommand{\arraystretchdefault}{ \renewcommand {\arraystretch} {\arraystretchdefaultl} }
        \arraystretchdefault

        \newcommand {\scalelinespace} [1] {\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}}

        \newlength{\tabcolsepdefaultl}
        \setlength{\tabcolsepdefaultl}{2.12mm}
        \newcommand{\tabcolsepdefault}{ \setlength{\tabcolsep}{\tabcolsepdefaultl} }
        \tabcolsepdefault

        \newlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}
        \setlength{\arraycolsepdefaultl}{2.12mm}
        \newcommand{\arraycolsepdefault}{ \setlength{\arraycolsep}{\arraycolsepdefaultl} }
        \arraycolsepdefault
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h t p]
    % Table options
    % Caption
    \caption{\Large \textbf{A table with multi-rows and multi columns}}
    \label{table:fit_WT_par}
   % Center the table
    \centering
    % Table contents
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}C *{3}{|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\arraybackslash}C}}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{WT Model}} \\
        \hline
 \textbf{Fit Type} & \textbf{GEV MP R} & \textbf{G58-850} & \textbf{E-92} \\
 \hline
 Polynomial Fit According to Eq. & \RaggedLeft $c_{7 }= -9.7, \; c_{6} = 531$, $c_{5} = -122, \; c_{4} = 152$, $c_{3} = -111, \; c_{2} = 473$, $c_{1} = -10927270, \; c_{0} = 105$ &
\justifying $c_{8} = -1.30, \; c_{7} = 85.3$, $c_{6} = -236, \; c_{5} = 360$, $c_{4} = -328979, \; c_{3} = 184$, $c_{2} = -6194947, \; c_{1} = 113$, $c_{0} = -874$ &
$c_{9} = -0.0535, \; c_{8} = 2.79$, $c_{7} = -53.1, \; c_{6} = 364$, $c_{5} = 150, \; c_{4} = -416$, $c_{3} = 290, \; c_{2} = -972$, $c_{1} = 1609, \; c_{0} = -104$ \\
 \hline
 Approximate Cubic According to Eq. & $C_{p, \, \max} = 0.3926$ & $C_{p, \,\max} = 0.4453$ & $C_{p, \, \max} = 0.4729$ \\
 \hline
 Exponential (Eq. ) & $K_{p} = 2.687, \; \beta = 2.201$ & $K_{p} = 12.88, \; \beta = 1.532$ & $K_{p} = 11.12, \; \beta = 1.564$ %
 \\
 \Xhline{0.8pt}
 \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just used `multirow` and `multicolumn` for training purposes.